# In electronjs , what is the advantage of using child_process.fork in Main Process then in Renderer Process

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

As per electron js documentation, I can use node js modules. 
I wanted to create multiple separate processes to do heavy computation tasks without blocking UI.

I have 2 options to call node.js child_process.fork()

1. Calling child_process.fork() in Renderer Process for each task
2. I can use electron.js ipc module to send messages to Main Process from Renderer Process, then in Main Process, I can call child_process.fork() for each task

My Question is 
1. What is the advantage of using child_process.fork() in Main Process instead of Renderer Process?
2. Will it help my UI to be more smoother if I call child_process.fork() in Main process?

Note: I need to create multiple separate processes for each task so I cannot just use single Main Process to do heavy computation.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly I would not use `child_process`. Every Electron window has its own process so I would just run heavy tasks in their own Electron window. This also gives you access all of Node, Electron (and its IPC module), and the DOM. Basically everything JS has to offer :)

This way your main process can be left for core functionality and whatever UI you need will be in its own Electron window with no UI lag. The [Electron Quickstart](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md) has more info on how processes are handled in Electron.

Edit/Note: Electron windows can be created without UI, completely hidden.